# Calling codes after for loop was finished node.js

Tags: node.js, object, asynchronous, synchronization

I have a problem in my Node.js project.
I trying to return the "Report" object after the for loop finished.
my code(Updated):

```
            var apigClient = apigClientFactory.default.newClient({
            accessKey: '*******',
            secretKey: '*******',
            invokeUrl: '*******'
        });

        var pathTemplate = '*******';
        var method = 'POST';
        ///loop - calling API
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(jsonOutput).length; i++)
        {
            var body = {
                        *******: *******,
                        *******: *******
                    };
            apigClient.invokeApi({}, pathTemplate, method, {}, body)
            .then(function (result) {
                Report.numberOfSuccess++;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data));
            }).catch(function (result) {
                Report.numberOfFailed++;
                Report.reportList.push([jsonOutput[i].id,jsonOutput[i].currency]);
            });

        }
        /////finally
        console.log(Report);
```

my output:

```
{ reportList: [], numberOfSuccess: 0, numberOfFailed: 0 }
{ reportList: [], numberOfSuccess: 0, numberOfFailed: 0 }
{ reportList: [], numberOfSuccess: 0, numberOfFailed: 0 }
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
```

As you can see the the Report object is not ready.

what I need is:

```
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
{ reportList: [], numberOfSuccess: 4, numberOfFailed: 0 }
{ reportList: [], numberOfSuccess: 3, numberOfFailed: 0 }
{ reportList: [], numberOfSuccess: 2, numberOfFailed: 0 }
```

I'v tried to use promise and callback but it isn't works.

Comment: The body within the For-loop runs asynchronous code. Finally, you return a not yet filled report. Please comment in the console.log in the catch case.

Comment: Please have a look at e.g Promise.all

Comment: but when I added console.log to catch case it's doesn't print nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're executing async code inside a for loop which continues to execute in a synchronous fashion. The async calls will complete once the event loop processes its internal `FIFO queue` of callbacks.

As suggested above, you can use `promises` to deal with this but the caller function must be able to handle promises.

Another way of doing this if you don't want to deal with promises is to use the [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) module to process the array of items you're handling. You can look at the [eachLimit](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit) function which can help you with this.

---

```
var asyncFunc = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve('asyncFunc called...');
    });
};

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    asyncFunc()
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log('Result from asyncFunc is: ' + result);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

    console.log('Value of i is : ' + i);
}
```

So based on the above explanation, the above example will output the value of `i` for every iteration of the `for loop` before every call to the asyncFunc is processed.

---

```
var async = require('async');

var asyncFunc = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve('asyncFunc called...');
    });
};

var mainFunc = function(done) {
    var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    async.eachLimit(items, 1, function(item, callback) {
        asyncFunc()
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log('Result for item ' + item + ' is: ' + result);
            callback();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            callback(error);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);

            done(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Done processing items...');

            done();
        }
    });
};

mainFunc(function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Processing completed...');
    }
});
```

Here, using the `async` library, you can control how each item in your array is processed. Your caller function (i.e. `mainFunc`), could pass a callback that will be invoked when `async.eachLimit` completes.

In such case, I suggest you familiarize yourself more with `synchronous` and `asynchronous` operations.

### Update

Here is a simple example using only `promises`.

```
var asyncFunc = function(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log(item);
        resolve('asyncFunc called...');
    });
};

var mainFunc = function() {
    var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    var promises = items.map(asyncFunc);

    return Promise.all(promises);
};

mainFunc()
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

> The [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method returns a single Promise that resolves when
>   all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the
>   iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of
>   the first promise that rejects.

Comment: Having callback functions and promises within the same function is not a good style. I definitely suggest one just one form. In this case probably promises combined with $q or Bluebird is fine.

Comment: Thanks Maximo. can you please write the promise format (1) according to my code(because I little confuse where to put what).

Comment: @DorDana Updated my answer with an example using only promises. Hope this helps you out. Please accept this answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: @sfrehse "Having callback functions and promises within the same function is not a good style." Do you have a reference for this or is this your opinion? Most, if not all, of Node's Core libraries are written using callbacks. Also, Node.js added native promises in stable `version 0.12` so unless there is a benefit to using $q or Bluebird over native promises, why would I introduce another library?

Comment: @Maximo You are completely right, this is not a general recommendation for the entire code base since it is not easy possible (not impossible due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) . However, if it is possible code becomes more maintainable if you chose only one mechanism. And of course, $q and Bluebird are just techniques to simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to asyncronously fill up your `Report`. For example

```
 const callApi = ( jsonOutput ) => 
    return Promise.map( Object.keys(jsonOutput), ( key ) =>                 
       apigClient.invokeApi({}, pathTemplate, method, {}, body)
       .then( value => {
            Report.numberOfSuccess++;
            Report.reportList ( value );
            return value;
       } )
      .catch( () => Report.numberOfFailed++ )
)
```

However, your caller-function need to take promises into account. Finally you have have to call the function `callApi` by

```
callApi( jsonOutput ).then( report => console.log( "Report: ", report );
```

Comment: It does not help to write in uppercase. Please add your current solution.

Comment: as you can see I'm changing body every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Please add the entire function and also the function that calls the code.